# How to deploy pom.xml as SNAPSHOT with maven?

Tags: maven-2, nexus

I have a `pom.xml` and i want to use it as the parent `pom.xml` of my project.

and want to make the name for the `pom.xml` which was uploaded on Nexus like `ABC-root-pom-2.0.0-SNAPSHOT.pom`

so could anyone tell me what the command is using maven ?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried `mvn install` (installs into your local maven repo) or `mvn deploy` (deploys to your central repo)?

Comment: did not the exact command , i know how to deploy the jar, but did not know how to deploy pom.xml

Comment: Well, if your POM is a parent POM (`<packaging>pom</packaging>`), then it should get deployed automatically along with your jar files. Could you please add some more information to your question, e.g. project layout, etc.

Comment: @StefanFerstl so you means the pom should be upload to nexus when i deploy any jar based on it?

Comment: Yes. The POMs for your JARs will be uploaded to the same location as the JAR file. The Parent POM will be uploaded only if you build the whole project with all submodules, i.e. you execute `mvn deploy` from the location of your parent POM.

Answer (score 0):

Do not worry about what name the pom will have on the repository manager. The Maven repository format dictates that.

To get a Maven project with pom packaging deployed you have to do the normal steps of adding the distributionManagment to the pom and the credentials to the settings.xml. Then you run

```
mvn clean deploy
```

and thats it. Your other project can then reference it. An example for such a pom project is my [progressive-organization-pom](https://github.com/simpligility/progressive-organization-pom).